# Fetch data from a table using range/condition from columns of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table say "Table1" which have tons of data stored under a column name "Value", i have another table say "Table2" which have columns "from" and "to". I want to perform a 
"between" operation on column "value" of "Table1" and operands will be from "from" and "to" columns of "Table2".

For Example:

```
Table1      Value
            -------
            10
            11
            12
            13
            14
            15

Table2      from     to
           --------------
           1          3
           4          10
           5          15


operations to be performed:    select value from Table1 where value between 1 and 3 
                               select value from Table1 where value between 4 and 10
                               select value from Table1 where value between 5 and 15
```

Output will be union of these three operations.

P.S There in no common column among them.

Comment: so what will be the output?

Comment: @Deep Sharma Are u searching like this? **`SELECT
  t2.from1,
  t2.to1,
  Count(Value)
from
  table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
  ON t1.Value BETWEEN t2.from1 and t2.to1
Group by t2.from1, t2.to1`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  It returns any values in `Table1` that match a range in `Table2`.

DECLARE @t1 table (value int)
    DECLARE @t2 table (fr int, t int, iname varchar(20))

```
INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES
    (10)
    ,(11)
    ,(12)
    ,(13)
    ,(14)
    ,(15)

INSERT INTO @t2
VALUES
    (1, 3, 'First')
    ,(4, 10, 'Second')
    ,(5, 15, 'Third')

SELECT
  t1.value, t2.iname
FROM
  @t1 t1
INNER JOIN
  @t2 t2
    ON t1.Value BETWEEN t2.fr and t2.t
```

Returns:

```
10  Second
10  Third
11  Third
12  Third
13  Third
14  Third
15  Third
```

`10` shows twice since it matches two conditions.  You may want to add a `DISTINCT` to your select there.

Comment: how to add 1 more column say "image_name" from Table2 into output. I tried but it is giving me same image name for every row.

Comment: @DeepSharma see my edit.  You may be getting the same value in the test data because all the returned rows only match your third from and to numbers